# USB peripherals works only if plugged during boot

Tags: usb, xubuntu, 22.04

Using Xubuntu 22.04 LTS on an Alienware 17-R3, if I boot my PC with an external drive already plugged in, it works perfectly.

But if I plug it in after boot, it just isn't recognized. Neither `lsusb` nor `usb-devices` see the external drive at all.

What could it be? Is there a way I can somehow "reset" the system USB detection?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the system startup logs (and device detection) with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you plug in the USB devices.